# Logistic Regression: wald chi-square

Tags: regression, logistic

I am running a logistic regression with a binary dependent variable and 5 class independent variables.

One information the software I use returns, is the following:

Effect / DF  /  Wald / Pr > ChiSq

Var1 / 1    / 150 / <.0001

Var2 / 3 / 119 / <.0001

Var3 / 8 / 157 / <.0001

Var4 / 6 / 1553 / <.0001

Var5 / 4 / 15975 / <.0001

Concerning the data above I have two questions:

I)  How can I interpret the fact that for var5 the value of the wald chi-square is so much higher than the values of the remaining variables?  And is it a bad indicator of the regression quality?

II) I saw the impact of a regression variable calculated as the division between the wald chi-square value of the variable and the total sum of all the variables wald chi-square values (shown in percentage….is this example var5 would represent 88.9% of the probability resulting from the logistic regression), but found no statistical grounds for this methodology. Anyone knows this methodology or others?

Any guidance will be helpful

Comment: All of these chi-squares are hugely significant. However, to compare the effects of one variable to another, I would use effect sizes, not chi-square itself and certainly not p.

Comment: Sorry, but has I'm new to this issues, can you give me some guidance on 'effect sizes' (probably the indication of articles or books about this issue).

Comment: The most common effect size measure for logistic regression is the odds ratio.